# QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display while launching application

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qt4

I have a QT application which have multiple widgets and QT graphics. I created a package and application works fine in two machine but when I tried to execute in third machine its throwing error

```
 QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

Whether I need to install something related to graphics. Anyinput is a great help

Comment: Missing libxcb? Which distro and which Qt version?

Comment: is the `DISPLAY` env var properly set? Are you trying to use the program locally or remotely? Is there even an x-server on that machine?